# Google Plus OAuth PHP 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I am trying to setup authentication with google plus using [their tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/php). I followed the directions verbatim, changing the `client id` and the `client secret` in `signin.php`. For the record, the google plus API is enabled in the google developer console. I update file permissions as instructed as well (`chmod +x signin.php` and `chmod -R 555 vendor/`). However, upon loading my authentication URL (which happens to be at the `auth_test/` sub directory of my domain, and clicking the sign in button, the console throws a `401 (unauthorized)` for the `get` request sent `/activites.` I have researched the problem and see that this can be caused by an invalid token, but I dont see how that can be because everything has been setup in `singin.php.` Much help would be appreciated...

Comment: Are you sure that you can do a `curl` request?....maybe you don't have the curl extension enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the state of your app if disconnected to refresh the `$tocken`.

> Google API office Docs on Handling API Errors
>
> ```
> 401: Invalid Credentials
> ```
>
> Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either
>   expired or invalid.

```
{   "error": {
>     "errors": [
>       {
>         "domain": "global",
>         "reason": "authError",
>         "message": "Invalid Credentials",
>         "locationType": "header",
>         "location": "Authorization",
>       }
>     ],
>     "code": 401,
>     "message": "Invalid Credentials"   } }
```

> Suggested action: Refresh the access token using the long-lived
>   refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow,
>   as described in Authorizing Your App

Also its is clearly commented in singin.php at line no. 98 :

> ```
>     // Normally the state would be a one-time use token, however in our
>     // simple case, we want a user to be able to connect and disconnect
>     // without reloading the page.  Thus, for demonstration, we don't
>     // implement this best practice.
>     //$app['session']->set('state', '');
> ```

Thus in your case it appears that your app is disconnected and thus causing the `$token` to become empty. Hence forcing this code block at line no: 91

```
if (empty($token)) {
        // Ensure that this is no request forgery going on, and that the user
        // sending us this connect request is the user that was supposed to.
        if ($request->get('state') != ($app['session']->get('state'))) {
            return new Response('Invalid state parameter', 401);
        }
```